# What does "companion" mean in a book's title?

Tags: meaning, book-title

In the title of book [The Cambridge Companion to Philosophical Methodology](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-companion-to-philosophical-methodology/781DFE6A15FF4092B65EB13067BD3D91), does "companion" mean this books is a complement to another book?

Bing's dictionary says:

> Companion
>
> 1. ...
> 2. one of a pair of things intended to complement or match each other:
>    "a companion volume"
>    synonyms:
>    complement · counterpart · fellow · mate · twin · other half · match · accompaniment · supplement · addition · adjunct · appendage ·
>    accessory · auxiliary
>
> - a book that provides information about a particular subject:
>   "the Oxford Companion to English Literature"
>   synonyms:
>   handbook · manual · guide · reference book · ABC · primer · vade mecum · enchiridion · instruction book

According to Bing, does "companion" here mean a standalone book, which is "a book that provides information about a particular subject"?

Does "companion" imply at which level the book is presented? Advanced, intermediate, or introductory?

How can one tell whether "companion" in a book's title means it accompanies another book or it is a standalone book?

Comment: The point of the word *companion* in a title is to tell **beginners** they have a friend in this book.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Hold your horses, Yosef! I have *The Cambridge Companion to Richard Strauss* and *The Richard Strauss Companion* and I wouldn't recommend either to beginners :)

Comment: Just like 'guide', it's a transferred usage, really personification ('companion' or 'guide' being prototypically a person who helps/supports one along the way).

Comment: It is not clear why this question was closed as 'off-topic'. It seems to be a perfectly sensible question about the use of a word that is only loosely related to its core meaning and is arguably problematic. The word, when used this way, may well be a marketing device with no precise meaning, but that should be a part of the answer, rather than a reason for closing the question.

Comment: @jsw29 this unresolved question (deleted and closed forcibly) discusses the same issue, and might interest you https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610507/what-differences-are-between-the-following-words-used-in-naming-books-in-the-le

Comment: Thank you for this question, which sent me back to the 'Oxford Companion to the English Language', which deserves to be cited in this site more often.  It tells us that 'Companion', from 13th century French, is "A work of reference, usually arranged alphabetically, that is there to be consulted whenever needed."  It explains rather than defines, and is a bit like a sensible, well-informed  friend.  So not so far from its then French meaning if a messmate (from 'com-' for 'with' and 'panis' for bread), so my OCEL friend tells me.  That is exactly what it is to me.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/publications/collections/cambridge-companions

Comment: I wouldn't recommend *The Silmarillion* to my worst enemy. I couldn't even make it through book one, let alone *that*. - Cambridge? Talking about the school or the dictionary? If it's the dictionary, it's reference material. The school; it's a book they sell for money with their brand on it, that you can find in the *users also bought* section.

Comment: *ride on coattails* "To benefit from someone else's success; to use someone else's success as a means to achieve one's own." https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ride+on+coattails

Comment: What does "*The Cambridge* Companions mean? is a different question. It's a collection : "Collection: The Cambridge Companions to Philosophy and Religion" - Cambridge*'s* Companion, is how 2b should be used. With no possessive, you're talking about 2a; *some other book*. - Well, they're not going to title it, The Cambridge *student's* Companion for a bunch of other books that we're going to make you buy.

Answer (score 11):

A companion is a work intended to keep you oriented in a subject area that is new to you, especially when you encounter something about which you know little or nothing. It will cover many sub-topics succinctly so you can make progress while reading other works, and not just skip over references that make no sense to you.

Compare:

> The Companion is aimed at students encountering Old English literature
> for the first time, who require clear guidance and orientation in an
> unfamiliar field.
>
> The Cambridge Companion to Old English Literature

Answer (score 9):

The third.

OED:

> **Companion**
>
> II.10.a.
>
> **A handbook or reference book on a specific subject; a manual, a guide.** *Frequently as part of the title of such a work.* Cf. *vade-mecum* n. 1.
>
> 1621 A Relation of some speciall points concerning the State of
> Holland, or the Provident Counsellours Companion. *(title)*
>
> 1903 At the beginning of the Canadian ‘Parliamentary Companion’ a
> whole page is headed in large capitals, ‘Whippers-in’. *Westminster
> Gazette 9 October 12/1*
>
> 2001 This softback book is a must have companion for any serious
> visitor. *Art Room Catalogue Spring Preview 40/1*

Answer (score 4):

If the title says ***Companion to + field/subject*** (such as *Philosophical Methodology* in your case), then it's a guide. Or as M-W puts it,

> a book, manual, etc., that provides information or advice about a particular subject
>
> - a ***companion*** to French New Wave cinema.

In order for *Companion* to mean *one of a pair*, than ***Companion to*** should be followed by the title of another book or show. See this example from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/companion):

> one that is closely connected with something similar
>
> - The book is a ***companion** to the television series with the same title*.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have already explained what *companion to X* means when used in book titles: it conveys the idea that the book is a manual, handbook, guide to X, which one will find it helpful to consult frequently while dealing with X (and will thus want to always have at hand while doing so). The implication is that the book is something that one will probably consult more often than other books about X, which discuss it in a more specialised way. The X in question can be either another book or some subject area.

That is indeed what the term is **supposed** to stand for. Recently, however, publishers have started using *companion to X* in the titles of books whose contents, upon scrutiny, turn out not to be any more helpful than the contents of numerous other books about X, and that one will not be likely to consult any more frequently than these other books. A companion to X is thus often **just another book about X**. The word *companion* is in these titles only because the publisher's marketing department wants you to think that the book is something that you will always want to have at hand while dealing with X, which makes it more likely that you will buy it.

The word *handbook* is sometimes used by publishers for the same purpose. Another part of the same marketing ploy is to combine *companion* or *handbook* in the title with the name of a venerable university, so as to create the impression that the authority of that entire university somehow stands behind the publication (while the truth is only that it is published by a publishing company that is loosely affiliated with the university).

Answer (score -3):

I think the following definition is clear:

> A companion book is a book that accompanies and elaborates on another already published book. The goal of a companion book is to provide the reader with a deeper understanding of concepts, themes, characters, places, and ideas in the original work.

([wappingersschools](https://www.wappingersschools.org/cms/lib/NY01001463/Centricity/Domain/1742/Companion%20Book%20Assignment.pdf))

Comment: But this definitely _does not_ apply to titles such as "The Oxford Companion to XXX".

Comment: Answer to the title, +1.